# Put custom made character on click of default number keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-keypad

I have some number character image as like below images:

[image][image][image][image]..... etc

Now, what I want is, when user click on the Number KeyPad "1" then image of 1 from above images is printed, when user click on Number keypad "2" then image of 2 from the above images is printed.

Answer (score 1):

Add an ImageView to your layout file, assume the file name is `main.xml`:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/digitImage" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

In the Activity that loads this layout file:

```
// declare digitImage as an instance variable
ImageView mDigitImage;
public void onCreate(Context ctx, AttributeSet attr) {
    // ... some init code..
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mDigitImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.digitImage);
}

// in onKeyDown method
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
            mDigitImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.digit1);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:
            mDigitImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.digit2);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
            ....
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. May be your code works. let me try it. But what if i press "2" and then "3" ? I dont want to replace the image but it should be display like images of 2 and 3.

Comment: Neevek: I have test your code. It works. But if i ues EditText and with inputType="number". then your code is not working.

Comment: The code snippet I provided has nothing to do with EditText, and you didn't mention EditText in your original question(though tagged it edittext), so I don't understand where that EditText comes from, and I bet that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a font with this images and then add them to your project's asset folder.

In your Activity's onCreate():

```
Typeface someFontTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/some_font.ttf");
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setTypeface(someFontTypeFace);
```

I did this to display Persian and digital numbers in my project's and it works fine for me:

[image] ----  [image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i dont have its font file. I just have the all character images.

Comment: There are some nice free tools that create fonts based on bitmap images. try one of them. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: so How to do it ? What are that tools name ?

Comment: Look at these links: http://www.yourfonts.com , http://users.breathe.com/l-emmett/sslogo.html , http://fontforge.sourceforge.net

Comment: Another way is to search for fantastic fonts that meet your conditions or is similar to what you want and use them. I am sure you will find something very similar to what you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

First u need to create a map like:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

and set the values as like this:

```
map.put(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0, R.drawable.0);
map.put(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1, R.drawable.1);
.....
```

and in onKeyDown() method:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

       Integer image = map.get(keyCode);
       if(image != null) {
           imageView.setImageResource(image);
       }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```